# Square wave oscillator on PSpice simulation

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator, pspice, square

I'm new to PSpice and here I was trying to simulate a square wave oscillator using a LM193 on PSpice. Here is the circuit that I've created there:

[image]

Edit: The capacitor C1 has an IC set to 0

However, when I plot the waveform of Vout, this is the obtained result:

[image]

Even though this form "resembles" a square wave, it's not even close to what I wanted. I'd be really thankful if someone could explain a couple of things to me:

1. Why is the signal oscillating only between 0 and -5V? Shouldn't it be between -Vsat and + Vsat, where Vsat is used to designate the saturation voltage of the Op Amp? What have I done wrong in this circuit?
2. Moreover, isn't the output voltage supposed to be more symmetrical (therefore resembling more a square wave)? If someone could give me some advice on how to make it more like it I'd appreciate it.

Thanks a lot for your attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LM193 has an open collector output therefore, it needs a pull up resistor: -

[image]

Examples of a relaxation oscillator using a generic op-amp with push-pull output on the left and a single-supply connected LM193 (that requires a pull-up) on the right: -

[image]

Without a pull up resistor, the 100 ohm positive feedback resistor and 1 kohm resistor power the open collector output but not from the positive supply but from 0 volts. Hence that is why you see such an asymmetrical output voltage. Use a 1 kohm pull up resistor to V+ and increase R1 from 100 ohms to something like 10 kohm. 100 ohm is much too low for decent operation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Managed to solve it!
By the way, could you enlighten on the role of the negative feedback resistor R on the waveform and also what would be a reasonable range of values for it?
Thank you!

Comment: I believe you mean the 50 kohm in your question yes? A range of a few hundred ohms to many tens of kohm is usually fine without any small_print. It controls how fast or how slow the capacitor is charged in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 1):

A few problems here.

LM193, LM293, and LM393 are open collector 0V to Rout to  V+ outputs. Your design is missing the pullup R.

Then you want to minimize the swing to Vin+,- so R1 should be much larger than R2.  e.g. 10x

Also feedback R's should never be 100 Ohms. This is too low and will be current limited.

See page 3 https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lm193.pdf

Now try again using R2=100K split into 2 R's to Vcc and 0V. Then make R1= same or bigger than R2.

NOW you can use a single supply.

What happens when you reduce the feedback R on Vin-?

How is that different from increasing R1 for lower hysteresis?

[See here](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%205e-9%2049.687244006919805%2050%205%2050%0Aa%20256%20240%20336%20240%208%205%200%201000000%202.2093347721210397%201.6666485771268333%20100000%0Ar%20256%20176%20336%20176%200%20142000%0Ac%20256%20224%20192%20224%200%201e-10%202.2093347721210397%0Ag%20192%20224%20192%20240%200%0Ar%20192%20288%20256%20288%200%20100000%0Ar%20256%20288%20336%20288%200%20100000%0AR%20256%20336%20224%20336%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20336%20128%20336%20176%200%201000%0AR%20336%20128%20336%20112%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20336%20176%20336%20240%200%0Aw%20256%20176%20256%20224%200%0Aw%20256%20256%20256%20288%200%0Aw%20336%20240%20336%20288%200%0Ar%20256%20288%20256%20336%200%20100000%0Ag%20192%20288%20192%20304%200%0A403%20144%20336%20416%20384%200%209_64_0_4362_10_0.1_0_2_9_3%0Ax%20293%20196%20312%20199%204%2014%20Rfb%0A403%2064%20224%20192%20288%200%2011_64_0_4354_5_0.1_0_2_11_3%0A38%201%200%2025000%201000000%20Rfb%0A)