# LM393 voltage comparator is not working

Tags: comparator

[image]
In my Lm 393 comparator, my output is not coming proper square wave.picture is shown below. I have described about my circuit.

I am using voltage comparator LM393 for comparing two signals, one signal is my reference signal which is a triangle wave, with voltages 2.08 volt generated by 555 timers above 200kHZ giving to the input terminal of inverting side of LM393 and input signal or modulating signal which voltage is less than 2.08 giving from function generator as a sinusoidal signal in the range of 1 Hz to 20kHz in the noninverting side of LM393.

My question is when I am providing two signals it should be compared and give a square wave, but LM393 only taking triangle wave, sin wave is not going?

In this picture below, I am referring to this circuit, please tell me what 's wrong in this circuit, when I am taking triangle wave from 555 timer ad providing into the comparator and another signal providing from the generator.

[image]

Comment: Read the datasheet and ensure your CM inputs range is valid and same for supply and output should follow the differential levels.

Comment: yes, I have read it everything is okay, but still not working.

Comment: If you understand then define each pin voltage

Comment: okay, in my triangle wave is going to the inverting pin (pin no -2) voltage is 4.5 volt for non inverting pin sin wave is going to the pin no -3, voltage is 5 volt , pin no-5 as VCC of LM393, 5 volts.

Comment: Show your circuit. Also note [the open collector](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/506493/square-wave-oscillator-on-pspice-simulation/506496#506496) asked recently and solved.

Comment: You have a 4 channel oscilloscope - you need to use it as one. || If you show the LM393 pins 1 2 3 simultaneously you and we can see what is REALLY happening. At present your diagram plus text shows what you think or hope or guess is happening.

Answer (score 3):

LM393 input common mode voltage range is 0 V to Vcc - 1.5 V. In the comments you say:-

> my triangle wave is going to the inverting pin (pin no -2) voltage is
> **4.5** volt for non inverting pin sin wave is going to the pin no -3, voltage is **5** volt , pin no-5 as VCC of LM393, **5** volts

5 V - 1.5 V = 3.5 V. It will not work properly if either input voltage goes above 3.5 V on a 5 V supply.

Comment: so, I need to increase my supply voltage of LM 393 using 6.5 volts instead of using 5 volts.

Comment: @ArijeetRoy: or reduce the input signal voltages.

Comment: okay , I reduce the voltage in the inverting side as 2 volts and give 2.5 volts into the noninverting side, it will work?

Comment: The circuit you have now provided should work (with some distortion at high signal level), but only if the audio input is AC coupled. You should put a capacitor ~1-10uF in series with each input channel. You can check that the comparator is working by varying R7 with no input. The PWM ratio should change, producing an average comparator output voltage similar to the pot voltage.

Comment: okay, I will do the same thing.

Comment: I will keep minimizing carrier voltage is near 2volts and pass the modulating signal above 2 volts,maybe the circuit will work.

Comment: @Bruce Abbott pleaser tells me , what is now my mistake , I have taken all the input considerations , now look the picture above , the result is coming but still if I remove or off my 3 pin signal , the output is still coming. I don't know what is happening. please help me,.

Comment: With no signal you should get a square wave with 50% duty cycle. The slow rise time is caused by parasitic capacitances charging through R6. You can improve the rise time by reducing the value of R6 to eg. 1k. Make sure your scope probe is on 10x. At 1x it has a lot of capacitance which will make the rise time look slower.

Comment: okay I will try this things.